# What is the best way to fetch the whole GraphQL tree in React?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

Let's say I have the following GraphQL schema:

```
type Cinema {
    name: String!    
    rooms: [Room]!
}

type Room {
    name: String!
    seats: [Seat]!
}

type Seat {
    number: Int!
    booked: Boolean!
}
```

In front view, I want to display a menu list on the left with collapsed navigation like:

- cinema name

  - room name 1

    - seat 1 (booked)
    - seat 2 (booked)
    - ...
  - room name 2

    - seat 1 (booked)
    - seat 2 (booked)
    - ...
  - ...

And on the right, I want to display a summary with the selected cinema name, the selected room name and a map with all seats.

So, the menu component is a classic case in GraphQL with pagination for each connection (rooms, seats). But the summary component **need all data before instanciation** and is not a child of the menu component:

```
<Page>
  <Menu />
  <Summary />
<Page />
```

**Yep, it's possible to handle this with this schema!**

Should I fragment my request according to my components, refetch until I have all data and save results in a dedicated state to send to the summary component?

**Nope, it's not possible to handle this with this schema!**

Should I make only one request without pagination and dispatch props manually to my components?

---

**Note 1**: I use Relay Modern as GraphQL client with [Relay-style cursor pagination](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm) but all suggestions are welcome.

**Note 2**: This example is simpler than my real use case. I have many nested pagination and my "summary" component need **all** data at initialization.

Comment: From the description above, the summary view is just a different representation of the seats of the selected room and cinema. So the query for Cinema > Room > Seats should be fine, shouldn't it? If that's the case it's not obvious to me why Summary component needs all the data up-front?

Comment: I guess your use case is more than this analogy. Summaries can be pre-calculated from the raw data to avoid costly recalculations on each render. E.g. the room seats are simple matrix and can be represented as numbers (one bit for each seat). This would be a much cheaper query than fetching raw seats data.

Comment: Yes, in my real use case, I have to deal with many nested pagination. If I want to respect the Relay way to do, I have to fragment my request according to my components. But then, I don't know how to retrieve all the data needed to operate my `Summary` component in the Relay way.